# tr and parentheses

Tags: replace, parentheses, tr

I have a huge file with SQL queries on each line.
But that file has some bugs, and re-creating it would take too much time.
I have some lines with missing semicolon.
I see that these lines always end with ) followed by the newline.
So what I did is following:

```
cat file.sql | tr ')\n' ');\n' > new_file.sql
```

But this simply adds semicolon on ALL lines. I don't understand, it seems it doesn't detect the parentheses. I simply want to find all lines ending with parentheses without a semicolon, and add it before newline.

How can I do that? I know `sed` cannot deal with newlines, so I thought `tr` is the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `tr` for this, it works on *sets of characters* rather than strings - the command you have will translate all `)` into `)` and all `\n` into `;`, ignoring the excess character in set 2:

```
pax> echo 'line1()
...> line2();
...> line3()' | tr ')\n' ');\n'

line1();line2();;line3();
```

`sed` is a better tool for this job:

```
sed 's/)$/);/' file.sql > new_file.sql
```

What that does is to replace any `)$` sequence (closing parenthesis at the end of a line) with `);`. You can see it in action in the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'line1()
...> line2();
...> line3()' | sed 's/)$/);/'

line1();
line2();
line3();
```

Comment: hm interesting. can you tell me what that dollar symbol means for sed? its working, thanks.

Comment: In `sed`, the `$` sign is end of line marker, otherwise it would replace the first `)` on each line rather than only those at the end.